# What happens to value stored in a variable in imacros?

Tags: imacros

I wanted to know that is value stored in a iMacros variable gets removed when loop ins started again, and if the value is removed then is there any way to store a value and use it again and again over multiple loops and updating its value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the ‘startTime’ variable which demonstrates that ‘iMacros’ stores its value and updates with every loop.

```
SET startLoop 1
SET !LOOP {{startLoop}}
SET startTime EVAL("('{{!LOOP}}' == '{{startLoop}}') ? '{{!NOW:yymmdd_hhnnss}}' : '{{startTime}}';")
PROMPT {{startTime}}
```

Or do you want to store a value between several pressing the ‘Play (Loop)’ button?